# Background image positioning on desktop vs. mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, position, wordpress-theming

I'm setting up a new Wordpress site and am stuck on how to position my logo (header image)/background image. The photo below is how I want it to look & how it currently appears on a desktop. However, it gets cut off on mobile and I think it has to do with how I set it up...

[image]

My header image is actually transparent and what you see is the background image. So my question is, is there a way that I can position it properly on mobile devices too? Or, is there a better way to do this?

The reason I chose to set it as the background image rather than a header image is that I wasn't sure how I could get it to actually touch the top of the page if set as the header image.

If you want to see my actual website, [it's here](http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/). I'm using the Brunch Pro theme.

Any help or ideas would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Please post your header's html and css code

Comment: Can you tell me where to find that? I did all of this using the customizer in Wordpress.

Comment: Do you have knowledge in CSS? You could just use CSS3's flexbox to make your background-image's size responsive

Comment: Could you share the link of your test or development environment where you are facing this problem? Or is it on localhost?

Comment: I do have some experience with CSS. Here is my test site: http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this css to active theme style.css file.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
    body.custom-background {
        background-image: url(http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/backgroundlogo2.jpg);
        background-position: 50% top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-size: 70% auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That definitely works better than before however it's getting stretched out of proportion now. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: There is white space in original image. http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/1backgroundlogo.png.

Comment: you can fix this if you set the background image as static?

Comment: Should I crop the white part of the image off? And static rather than scroll?

Comment: Yes. you want crop the image. you can user scroll. static means you cannot change image from admin.

Comment: ok, I cropped the image but now it's centered on the desktop view and really stretched out on mobile.

Comment: do not set the cropped image as background. upload the image in theme folder and set in css.

Comment: Should I still be using that code above? Because it isn't showing anything now that I removed the image that was set as the background.

Comment: set the not cropped images as background and upload the cropped image in theme folder not in background image

Comment: ok, I set the uncropped image as the background and then I used the code above with the image that I uploaded. I looks like it's just using the uncropped image though. I don't think I really understand what I'm doing :/

Comment: Wordpress is not letting me save that because it says "unexpected token 'body'....."

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the size differently on a phone vs. a tablet? After looking at it for a bit, I think I'd prefer it to be a little wider but only on the phone. Not sure if that's possible. This is kind of new to me.

Comment: Yes. We can fix in tablet